# Understanding proof step in group representation theory for finite $G$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

As part of a proof that, for a finite group $G$, the matrix components $T_{ji}$ of any finite-dimensional representation with respect to an o.n. basis form a set of $n^2$ complex-valued functions on $G$, the author gives the following manipulations which I couldn't follow. Note that the summation convention is used (except, of course, for $g$, where the summation is shown explicitly):

[image]

I am wondering, in each case, how the deductions (5.23) and (5.24) are made from the lines above it. I'm not sure it's necessary to even know that this is related to group representation theory, as this feels like an exercise in linear algebra. At any rate, the $T_{(i)}$ are inequivalent representations of $G$ on different vector spaces $V_i$, and here we see their matrix representation components in some bases. $T$ is a single representation on a given vector space $V$. Importantly, $A: V_1 \to V_2$ is any linear map. This is why Szekeres (Chapter 5.3 of A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics) writes "is an arbitrary operator". But I am struggling to use this fact to see how it can be "eliminated" in (5.23) and (5.24). Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Sorry about that, I usually don't. This was just a really quick question so thought it was OK. Won't do that again. @Shaun

Comment: Please type it up at some point in the near future, then.

Answer (score 0):

For 5.23 take $A_{j}^{i}=1$ for any $i,j$.
For 5.24 take $A_{j}^{i}=\delta_{j}^{i}$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Does that work even when we're using the summation convention here?

Comment: I read representation of finite groups by Serre long time ago, I remember these two formulas but have forgotten details. I am able to answer your original question but can’t add more about representation theory. So if it helps you, let us go through it again: the formula before 5.23 says it holds for all A, so to obtain 5.23 you plug in the case when A is the matrix with all elements being 1. The formula before 5.24 holds for any A so to obtain 5.24 you plug in the case when A is the identity matrix. So both 5.23 and 5.24 are special cases of the formula before them respectively.

Comment: Would you be able to show these explicitly in your answer? My trouble is that just setting, for example, $A^b_j = 1$ in the line above (5.23) seems to "break" the summation convention, and I can't then see how to recover the required result.

Comment: I've thought about it now, and I don't quite think your method is correct but it gave me the right idea. We need to use the $dimV_1dimV_2$ different matrices which have only one 1 and the rest 0s (the standard basis of this vector space of matrices). This then leads to the required conclusion.